# Правильный подход к созданию копий

Tags: ооп, c++

Постановка задачи следующая. Имеется базовый класс, с указателями на который идет работа. Пользователи базового класса не знают детали реализации, но должны иметь возможность создавать копии объектов. Сейчас делано это примерно так:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual Base* copy() const = 0;
    virtual void show() const = 0;
};

class ClassInt : public Base
{
public:
    ClassInt(int data) : _data(data) {}

    Base* copy() const { return new ClassInt(_data); }
    void show() const { /* показать целое */ }

private:
    int _data;
};

class ClassDouble : public Base
{
public:
    ClassDouble(double data) : _data(data) {}

    Base* copy() const { return new ClassDouble(_data); }
    void show() const { /* показать дробное */ }

private:
    double _data;
};
```

Т.е., работая с указателем на Base, мы можем показать его через show, не думая о реализации. А если нам нужно получить клон, то вызываем copy.
Честно говоря, меня  терзают смутные сомнения, что подобное делается элегантнее. Или все нормально?

Comment: для создания копий вообще то есть конструктор копирования. Или он Вам не подходит?

Comment: KoVadim, но как? Я же работаю с указателем на Base и не знаю ничего о классе реализации:

ClassInt* ci = new ClassInt;
Base* obj = ci;
Base* copyOfObj = ? как получить копию obj ?

Comment: Я забыл, что в плюсах нет виртуальных конструкторов. Да, тогда делайте функцию copy. Это будет проще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не могу понять, что вам не нравится и при чём здесь вообще функция `show`. Мои замечания: лучше использовать стандартное имя для таких функций, а именно `clone`; лучше возвращать объект этого же класса, то есть `ClassInt* clone() const { return new ClassInt(_data); }`, чтобы можно было написать `ClassInt* t=ClassInt(2).clone();`.

Comment: Show - это так, для примера. Да, я уже выяснил, что подход с клонированием - стандартный. Ну и насчет ковариантности тоже конечно верно.